# Minimum number of circles with 3 neighbors

Tags: geometry, circles, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

It is possible to arrange congruent circles on the plane in such a way that no two circles overlap and each circle adjoins exactly three other circles. The picture shows an example with 16 circles.

$\hskip1.2in$[image: circles]

Now my question is: what is the minimum number of circles required to create an arrangement that satisfies the criteria defined above? (How) can we prove optimality?

Comment: can the circles have diffirent radii?

Comment: @quantum Nope. Congruent circles.

Answer (score 4):

At this time I do not have a definitive answer, but my remarks on your question are longer than the comment limit.

What we wish to do is find a minimal (in the sense of number of vertices), 3-regular, planar matchstick (aka unit-distance) graph for which there is an embedding that the minimum distance from any vertex to any other non-adjacent vertex is strictly greater than the edge length.  There has been some research on this question:

[Can you place 24 unit circles in the plane so that each circle is tangent to exactly three other circles? What about 25 unit circles?](http://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/Sol01_1011.html)

It is known that the minimal 3-regular matchstick graph has 8 vertices, but this graph does not satisfy the last condition mentioned above (which I will call "minimum separation"), thus we know that the solution must require an even number of circles greater than 8.  I too suspect the minimum is 16 in the configuration you have shown.